# Limit selected item shown in control with Chosen plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-chosen

I'm using Chosen plugin

https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

I need to limit tag shown in textbox when user selected more than n items.
Now when user select more item control height increase to shown all item selected.
I would rather a parameter showing [3 item selected] when user exceeds 3 element selected.
There is a way to do it